# can two running processes share the complete process image in physical memory, not just part of it?

Tags: process, memory, process-management, fork, copy-on-write

can two running processes share the complete process image in physical memory, not just part of it?

Here I  am talking about the Linux operating systems(eg. Ubuntu).

**My thinking:**
I think it is  **False** in general because the only time it is possible is with copy-on-write during fork() and before any writes have been made.

**Que:** Can someone explain to me am I correct or not?
If I am wrong please give me some examples

Comment: Do you mean “Is this possible *in theory*? In some/any operating system?”  Or do you mean “Does operating system *X* allow a user/programmer to do this?”  In the latter case, you should specify what OS you are asking about.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: [Threads can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200469/what-is-the-difference-between-a-process-and-a-thread), otherwise there's problems with concurrent updates to the same data.